# How to make same height two div and center

Tags: html, css, css-float

how to floated two divs height makes same and after second div slip down, the container width fit child width and divs are center automatically? i apologise for my english. :(

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
.container{
text-align:center;
display:block;
background-color:grey;
}

.left {
    background-color:#EFF5FB;
    width: 510px;
    float: left;
    min-height:50px;

}

.right {
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% - 520px);
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 520px);
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 520px);
    width: -o-calc(100% - 520px);
    min-width:510px;
    background-color: #00f;
    height:100%;
    //min-height:50px; (edited)
}
.clear{clear:both;}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="left"><p>paragraph 1</p><p>paragraph 2</p></div>
<div class="right"><p>paragraph 1</p></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

[i want to do this] https://i.stack.imgur.com/56gwt.jpg

http://jsfiddle.net/SpSjL/3268/  (edited again!)

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the floating and give `width: auto;` for `.left` & `.right` elements, at the certain point when the width is reduced. Further, to make the `.container` center aligned give `max-width` and align it using `margin-left: auto;` & `margin-right: auto;`

Below is the media query:

```
    @media (max-width: 600px){
        .container{
            max-width: 400px;
            margin:0 auto;
        }
         .left, .right{
             float: none;
             width: auto;
             padding: 10px;
         }
         .left p{
             padding-bottom: 10px;
         }
    }
```

Padding bottom for `<p>` tag is added to get the spacing between the elements.

Find the working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/MasoomS/3xw2qpb8/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a simple class in CSS, with width: 50% margin:0 padding: 0 and put that class into the two divs that you want put together, then you can make a media query like this example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    theClassCreated{width:100%;}
}
```

Comment: first div size should fixed, the other div takes up the rest of the space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use table to make two div of same height.

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td style="float:right";>Jill</td>
    <td style="float:left";>Smith</td>      
  </tr>
</table>
```

As the `<td>` element of table has default display: table-cell property make them to  display in same height.

Later on when they flip because of window size change you can add media query to change as you want.